# Why jQuery click & change events firing at different times on Chrome vs Safari or IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, jquery-events

I'm working on fixing a cross browser bug on a website, and have found the cause of it to be that the jQuery Click & Change events fire at different times depending on your browser.

For instance on Chrome and Firefox the Click event fires before the change event. While on Safari or IE 11 it's the other way round.

I would have expected that by using jQuery this would have not occurred as jQuery is known for being well tested for cross browser compatibility.

Anyway, **Is it possible with jQuery/JavaScript to make sure the code in the .click function is always executed before the code in the .change function regardless of the browser?**
I realise, with the example below, I could just put everything in one of the events but am wondering if what I'm asking is possible.

Here is an example of the code:

```js
var $input = $('input[name="foobar"]');
$input.click(function() {
  console.log( "Click event called for input with value " + $(this).val() );
  });
$input.change(function() {
  console.log( "Change event called for input with value " + $(this).val() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="http://example.com/checkout/add/" id="product_addtocart_form" method="post" name="product_addtocart_form">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label for="option_1">
  <input value="10" name="foobar" checked="checked" data-name="foo" id="option_1" type="radio">
  <span>Foo</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="option_2">
 <input value="12" name="foobar" data-name="bar" id="option_2" type="radio">
 <span>Bar</span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)" title="Add to Basket" type="button">Add to Basket</button>
</form>
```

If you run the snippet and click on the radio buttons, you'll see in the console the order of the events being fired.

I've tested on Chrome 60, FireFox 54, Safari 10.1 and Internet Explorer 11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to define a custom event and use `.trigger()` to dispatch the event within `click` event handler

```js
var $input = jQuery('input[name="foobar"]');
$input.on("click", function() {
  console.log( "Click event called for option with value " + jQuery(this).val() );
  $(this).trigger("customChange", ["customChange called from click handler"])
  });
$input.on("customChange", function(e, customChangeData) {
  console.log( "Change event called for option with value " + jQuery(this).val(), customChangeData );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="http://example.com/checkout/add/" id="product_addtocart_form" method="post" name="product_addtocart_form">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label for="option_1">
  <input checked="checked" data-name="foo" id="option_1" name="foobar" type="radio" value="10">
  <span>Foo</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="option_2">
 <input data-name="bar" id="option_2" name="foobar" type="radio" value="12">
 <span>Bar</span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button title="Add to Basket" type="button">Add to Basket</button>
</form>
```